# What does "green implementation" mean?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes in source codes I see something like:

```
// TODO: Do we assume searchChar is usually relatively small;
//       If so then calling toString() on it is better than reverting to
//       the **green implementation** in the else block
```

([from here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/CharSequenceUtils.html#line.136))

My guess is that *green implementation* refers to quickly written code that works correctly, but is capable for further optimization and refactoring. Am I right?

Comment: @DocBrown this example is from apache commons lib source code; the same term I heard a few times from other developers outside our organization. If it was so specific, I couldn't hear/read it in several sources, if it was common, I could just google an answer, without need of asking here.

Comment: Well, you could have written that into your question first hand, without any context such a question is very unclear. That is why it got closed. You can even try this now, maybe you can clarify enough to find five people voting to open your question again. Nevertheless I guess if you contact someone of the original devs of the code you are referring to, chances are much higher you will get an answer.

Comment: @DocBrown thank you, but I believe there is no need for this. If it was a common term, one of experienced programmers here answer this question quickly. Now I see it is unknown to most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've heard this is for green to refer to new or naive or inexperience (eg Green troops). So I would assume that the 'green implementation' refers to a very simplistic and potentially poor solution.

However, that's an assumption based on a couple of words that I don't see in common usage, so it could mean anything. maybe there was a "green project" that implemented solutions once and this refers to the output from that old project. Maybe it was written by a guy whose nickname was green.